# Figma: Can't draw a straight line using Pen and pencil tool what to do now

Tags: figma, figma-plugin

When I'm trying to draw a line it always shows me to BEND the line. How to draw a straight line in FIGMA using PEN Tool ?

I was expecting the correct answer